# there is no relation between phonetic sounds and letters. explain?

Tags: phonology, phonetics

So I got this question in my midterm exam and it was out of nowhere. All what I could think about that time is that letters are written and sounds are spoken, the letters are made from a vowel and a consonant, but a sound is made from either a vowel or a consonant. and also the sound can be written in different letters such as the sound /k/ it can be written in C, K or, Q.
Can anyone give me other reasons??

Comment: Is this the opposite of the Korean system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the professor was actually getting at the arbitrariness of letter shapes, much like the sounds of a word are arbitrary ...? There is no straightforward reason *k* looks the way it does, or why *<dog>* refers to a particular animal in English (though there is some overlap, as in how *o* is spoken with rounded lips, and *crow* vaguely imitates the bird's sound).

Comment: sorry i missed the most important part of the question.
He said that There is NO 'one to one relationship between sounds and letters' why?

Comment: Well, obviously, there are letters like *x* which correspond to more than one phoneme. The letter *z* also represents the affricate *ts* in some orthographies.

Comment: But really, changing your question after you have received answers is generally unadvisable. Maybe (accept the answer you like the best here and) think about whether this topic really merits a new question.

Answer (score 4):

If the question is something like "Is it true that there is no relation between phonetic sounds and letters", the answer would be "No, that is false". For example, you can probably make a reasonable approximation of the sounds of the preceding sentences of English, just based on the letters. In some languages, you can be pretty sure what sounds correspond to what letters.

In the case of English, the relationship is very complicated and does not always work – it also depends on what other knowledge you can bring to bear on getting the pronunciation. For example, [θ] and [ð] are both represented with "th" in spelling, but you can predict that if you can distinguish the historical source of a word with "th". If you know that "either" is Germanic and "ether" is Greek, you can predict the pronunciation of "th" (in Germanic words, initial [ð] is limited to articles / demonstratives). Unless you spend a lot of time trying to discern subtle rules about spelling in English (and the origin of words in English), English is fairly irregular in the relationship between letters and sounds. However, "k" is not pronounced as [p], or as [v], or as [l], so saying that there is *no* relation is a bit of hyperbole.

On the chance (suggested by triplee) that the intended point is that letter shapes don't resemble articulatory diagrams, that's generally true except that Korean Hangul is (historically) a conventionalized articulatory diagram.

Comment: Agreed. But only a **bit** of hyperbole. While I used to teach historical etymology, I don't recommend it as a way to learn English if you're not already a native speaker and/or fascinated by linguistics. In general, non-native speakers should learn English spellings by rote, the same way one learns German noun plurals or genders by rote. That's the same way the native speakers learned them, which is why native speakers spell pretty badly for the most part.

Comment: I agree that it's bad for language learners, and should only be practiced by licensed linguists who already know the language, and are familiar with SPE.

Comment: I'm sorry ,but I believe you didn't get my question or i didn't explain it well. I was actually aiming at that 'There is No relation, Why is that?'

Comment: I understand, the problem is that the question has a false presupposition, as I explained. That will make it difficult for you to answer the question.